# dijit.form.FilteringSelect onChange event is not firing

Tags: dojo

Hi I am using the connect to setup the onChange event but it is not firing - no errors being generated and I am at a loss as to what the problem is.

```
 <select name='value(serviceRefId)' dojoType='dijit.form.FilteringSelect' id='serviceRefId'>
 <option value='0'></option>
 <option value='10109'>General Surgery</option>
 <option value='10108'>Internal Medicine</option>
 <option value='10111'>Laboratory</option>
 <option value='10113'>Other</option>
 <option value='10112'>Paediatrics</option>
 <option value='10110'>Radiology</option>
 </select>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
           dojo.connect(dojo.byId("serviceRefId"), 'onChange', function(event){ 
                 alert('ok ' + event);
           });
      });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no onChange on the DOM element, which will fire. Instead there is an event in the form dijit (widget) which has that name - but you'd need to use `dijit.byId` to get that component.

Try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
       // dojo.byId returns a DOMNode, not a dijit instance, replace dojo with dijit
       dojo.connect(dijit.byId("serviceRefId"), 'onChange', function(event){ 
             alert('ok ' + event);
       });
   });
 </script>
```